# How to add circular indicator to webview in flutter

Tags: flutter, webview

i am new here. Please forgive me if I make a mistake. I'm trying to make a payment screen. But I can't solve a small problem. I couldn't understand the cause of the problem. when i click to 'start payment' button it's show me that screen about 2 second.And it's look bad. [Bad View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyStn.png)

But good news  it's skip automatically normal payment screen. How can I show something else(Circular progress indicator, Lineer progres indicator etc.) on the screen instead of that String? My codes are below;

```
if (data['Status'] != "failure") {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: ((context) => CoreWebView(
                  htmlCode: data['paymentUrl'],
                ))));
      }
```

It's my WebView

```
    WebViewPlus(
              initialUrl: "https://example.com",
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
             //widget.html==data['paymentUrl'];
             
                var page = 'r"""${widget.htmlCode}"""';
                controller.loadString(page);
              },
         
           
              zoomEnabled: false,
             
            ),
```

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713912/how-to-show-loading-indicator-in-webview-flutter

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your widget a `StatefulWidget`.
2. Add a variable as `bool isLoading = true;`.
3. Change your code as:

   ```
   Stack(
     children: [
      WebViewPlus(
        onPageFinished: (url) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
        },
        initialUrl: "https://example.com",
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          //widget.html==data['paymentUrl'];
          var page = 'r"""${widget.htmlCode}"""';
          controller.loadString(page);
        },
        zoomEnabled: false,
      ),
      if(isLoading)
        Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()
      )
    ],
   ),
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not working. Bad View still stays on screen for about 2 seconds. Do you have another suggestion?