# How To Handle 404, web page not available and other errors in flutter webview app?

Tags: flutter, webview

Hello I am new to flutter but I am somehow created a webview app. Now I want some additional features like show custom page when url not loaded, or when web page not found. I have searched google a lot but not able to find any solution.

My code:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

import '../main.dart';

class Outlook extends StatefulWidget {
  const Outlook({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Outlook> createState() => _OutlookState();
}

class _OutlookState extends State<Outlook> {
  bool isLoading=true;
  late WebViewController _controller;
  final _key = UniqueKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Outlook"),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff6200EE),
          centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          WebView(
            key: _key,
            initialUrl: "https://outlook.office.com/",
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
              _controller.loadUrl("http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204");
            },
            onPageFinished: (finish) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
            },
          ),
          isLoading ? const Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
              : Stack(),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: const Navigation(),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: This is the answer of what you'r looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/58736112/17586537

Comment: This is the answer of what you'r looking for [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58736112/17586537](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58736112/17586537)

Answer (score 1):

To manage and display a custom error page, you can try my plugin [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview).

Use the `InAppWebView.onReceivedError` event to handle web page loading errors and the `InAppWebView.onReceivedHttpError` event to handle HTTP errors.
Also, on Android, you should set the `InAppWebViewSettings.disableDefaultErrorPage` property to `true`.

Here is an example using the current latest version 6 ([6.0.0-beta.18](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/6.0.0-beta.18)):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (!kIsWeb &&
      kDebugMode &&
      defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    await InAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(kDebugMode);
  }
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;

  handleClick(int item) {
    switch (item) {
      case 0:
        webViewController?.loadUrl(
            urlRequest:
                URLRequest(url: WebUri('https://www.notawebsite..com/')));
        break;
      case 1:
        webViewController?.loadUrl(
            urlRequest: URLRequest(url: WebUri('https://google.com/404')));
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Custom Error Page"),
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton<int>(
              onSelected: (item) => handleClick(item),
              itemBuilder: (context) => [
                const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                    value: 0, child: Text('Test web page loading error')),
                const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                    value: 1, child: Text('Test 404 error')),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: InAppWebView(
              key: webViewKey,
              initialUrlRequest:
                  URLRequest(url: WebUri('https://github.com/flutter')),
              initialSettings:
                  InAppWebViewSettings(disableDefaultErrorPage: true),
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                webViewController = controller;
              },
              onReceivedHttpError: (controller, request, errorResponse) async {
                // Handle HTTP errors here
                var isForMainFrame = request.isForMainFrame ?? false;
                if (!isForMainFrame) {
                  return;
                }

                final snackBar = SnackBar(
                  content: Text(
                      'HTTP error for URL: ${request.url} with Status: ${errorResponse.statusCode} ${errorResponse.reasonPhrase ?? ''}'),
                );
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
              },
              onReceivedError: (controller, request, error) async {
                // Handle web page loading errors here
                var isForMainFrame = request.isForMainFrame ?? false;
                if (!isForMainFrame ||
                    (!kIsWeb &&
                        defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS &&
                        error.type == WebResourceErrorType.CANCELLED)) {
                  return;
                }

                var errorUrl = request.url;
                controller.loadData(data: """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <style>
    ${await InAppWebViewController.tRexRunnerCss}
    </style>
    <style>
    .interstitial-wrapper {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 1em;
        line-height: 1.6em;
        margin: 0 auto 0;
        max-width: 600px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    ${await InAppWebViewController.tRexRunnerHtml}
    <div class="interstitial-wrapper">
      <h1>Website not available</h1>
      <p>Could not load web pages at <strong>$errorUrl</strong> because:</p>
      <p>${error.description}</p>
    </div>
</body>
    """, baseUrl: errorUrl, historyUrl: errorUrl);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Full project code example available at https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_examples/tree/main/custom_error_page

[image: Android example]
[image: iOS example]

Comment: How To Set Cookies In WebView as I want the user to  not logout for 1 week.

Comment: To manage cookies, use the [CookieManager](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/cookie-manager) class

Comment: Man your plugin is awesome but after the update your old codes are not working, please update them I have tried all the github examples and many of them showing error. In the above code initialSettings is not defined and many other variable please update and post here.

Comment: Thanks! As written in the answer, the code example is using plugin version 6.0.0-beta.18! Check the pubspec.yaml of the repository of the project example that I linked there

Comment: Thank you, can you plz tell me how can i show circularprogressindicator during loading webview? Also when I am using drawer it is not doing anything even after creating key