# How do I put SpinKitCircle into body?

Tags: flutter

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(

```
 appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('title'),
  ),

  body: SafeArea(
    child: WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (await _webViewController.canGoBack()) {
          await _webViewController.goBack();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'http://www.google.com',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          _webViewController = controller;
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

How can I put the Spinners code below into the code above?

Center(
child: SpinKitCircle(
size: 140,
color: Colors.white,
),
),

I don't know how to put the code in the body

Answer (score 0):

You will find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58736112/13365250).

Just replace CircularProgressIndicator with Center(child:SpinKitCircle(size: 140, color: Colors.white,),)